# Error when instantiating Chaincode with Java-SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Hey we are having a problem with our Fabric network.

After successfully installing the chaincode via some bash scripts we are trying to instantiate it using the Java SDK but keep getting the following error:

instantiation policy violation: signature set did not satisfy policy

The User requesting the instantiation is our CA-Admin, he should most definitely have permissions here.
We tried changing our chaincode instantiation policy a lot even to allow any org member to instantiate the chaincode, but to no avail.
If you need more information pls check it out in our github repo: https://github.com/PSE-blockchain-evoting/voting-network

Comment: Unclear how the linked github repo relates to the question. Also, please note that [Stack Overflow is an English site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange). So, linking to a repo which explains something in German is probably not very useful to many people. Better provide everything needed to understand your question inline, a.k.a. a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: We would need more details on your network setup ... e.g. how did you generate the credentials for your peers, how did you generate the credentials / MSPs in the channel config, etc